# How to extract the name of the model fit using auto.arima() function in the forecast package?

Tags: r

I want to extract the name of the model fit by `auto.arima()` in the forecast package.

For example, if I run the following code,

```
library(forecast)
auto.arima(WWWusage)
```

I get the output as follow:

```
Series: WWWusage 
ARIMA(1,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1     ma1
      0.6504  0.5256
s.e.  0.0842  0.0896

sigma^2 estimated as 9.995:  log likelihood=-254.15
AIC=514.3   AICc=514.55   BIC=522.08
```

I want to know how to extract the name of the model only, which is in this case `ARIMA(1,1,1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `as.character()` function has been overloaded in the package to return the value you are interested in.

```
fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
as.character(fit)
# [1] "ARIMA(1,1,1)"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for.